# Exception error while uninstalling extensions

Tags: magento-2.1

I have installed couple of extensions in my project ,but later i 
uninstalled by deleting folders from app/code and also from the database.now im getting exception  errors on frontend.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should not delete the folders directly. Please follow the below procedure

> DELETE FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE '%WeltPixel%'
>
> DELETE FROM `setup_module` WHERE `module` LIKE '%WeltPixel%'

After this you have to delete the module folders. Then upgrade, deploy cache process permissions etc.

Comment: Yes ,This will useful

Answer (score 0):

After you remove whole module catalog and entry in `setup_module` you propably will have to run `setup_upgrade`. If after that you still have error like this, clear `var/cache`, `var/page_cache`, `var/di` and `var/generation`.
If, after all these steps you still have such an error, maybe it means that this class from uninstalled module is used somewhere outside of your module.